# Developing a new component/sub application within an existing architecture

Tags: spring, architecture

I've got a fairly large Spring MVC application (80K loc) that I manage. Our team is going to be developing a new feature/sub-application.

The question is, should we build it/deploy it as its own application (a whole new  WAR) or build it/deploy it as part of the current application (part of the existing WAR)? Are there pros and cons to each?

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention how the existing app is. But I am going to assume that its not well maintained because you mentioned that it is going to be replaced. So it is best to go with a new application. There are multiple advantages to this approach opposed to bundling it with the existing application:

1. You can use the latest and greatest technologies(like microservices) which might not be possible with the older app due to several compatibility and technical debt issues.
2. You need not worry about potential regression issues.
3. Its a good opportunity for the team as a whole to learn the beauty of architecting a software.
4. Separation of concerns. i.e To keep your modules less coupled with each other.

There are a few cons to this approach as well but in the long run, its going to pay off.

1. The team might take a while to learn new stuff.
2. The implementation might suffer at a later stage if the designer is not  well versed with the functional aspects of the software.
3. Need a robust technical platform like Docker if you intend to go ultra-agile.

Answer (score 0):

This is a restatement of the old question:  Should I modify this application in-place, or scrap and rewrite.  The answer is almost always, to modify/upgrade in-place.  Please read [Joel's position](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html), on this and take it to heart.  I know the temptation is always to start from scratch, but it is almost always a mistake.

There are lots of ways to use the legacy code but not strongly couple it to the new application.  I've found [Working Effectively With Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052) to be a great resource on this.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear in my intention of the question. I'm more interested in whether a new component should be under our monolithic WAR or if it should be its own. I've updated to reflect that.

Comment: Ok, that's a different question.  If you can package it separately, you should do so.  As long as you don't need to share session state and such making two smaller applications is always preferable to one big one.